# SEGFAULT with a custom wx.PyGridCellEditor

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to create a version of a GridCellChoiceEditor which allows the list of choices to be changed at runtime.  The reason is that the choices to be presented are the result of a query on my data, so they will probably change every time the editor is used.  I am doing this be subclassing PyGridCellEditor, but whenever I run it, it segfaults immediately after creating the editor.  Here is my code, simplified for the purposes of testing to use a static list and only one cell:

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class ListEditor(wx.grid.PyGridCellEditor):

    def __init__(self, options):
        super(ListEditor, self).__init__()
        self.options = options

    def ApplyEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        grid.SetValue(row, col, self.value)

    def BeginEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        print('begin edit')
        value = grid.GetValue(row, col)
        index = self.options.index(value)
        self.combo.SetOptions(self.options)
        self.combo.SetIndex(index)

    def Create(self, parent, id, evtHandler):
        self.combo = wx.ComboBox(parent, id)
        print('combo created')

    def Clone(self):
        return ListEditor(self.options)

    def EndEdit(self, row, col, grid, oldval, newval):
        if oldval == newval:
            return False
        else:
            self.value = newval
            return True

    def Reset(self):
        pass

    def GetValue(self):
        return 'a'


class F(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(F, self).__init__(None)
        self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self, -1, (0, 0), (300, 300))
        self.grid.CreateGrid(1, 1)
        editor = ListEditor(['a', 'b', 'c'])
        self.grid.SetCellEditor(0, 0, editor)


app = wx.App(False)
f = F()
f.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: If it segfaults, you're almost certainly not doing anything wrong because whatever you do in wxPython, it's not supposed to crash. So you probably should report this as a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Create` method you need to call `self.SetControl(self.combo)` to let the editor base class know what is the real control.  You should also do `self.combo.PushEventHandler(evtHandler)` so the proper interactions with the grid are set up.